# Python - Concatenate Python query

Tags: python

I'm using the python-google-places script but I'm facing a problem when integrating the code into a function called with two parameters: "MyLocation" and "MyType".

"MyLocation" works well but "MyType" doesn't work.

Code that works (without a variable for "MyType")

```
# Configuration de l'encodage (a mettre dans tous les scripts)
# encoding: utf-8

####################################
### CLASS
#################################### 
def ExtractGoogleHotspots(Location,MyType):
        from googleplaces import GooglePlaces, types, lang
        YOUR_API_KEY = 'XXXXXXX'
        google_places = GooglePlaces(YOUR_API_KEY)
        # You may prefer to use the text_search API, instead.
        query_result = google_places.nearby_search(
            location=Location, #Location could be a name or coordinates in english format : 4.04827,9.70428
            keyword='',
            radius=1000,#Radius in meters (max = 50 000)
            types=[types.TYPE_PHARMACY] #Specify the Type
            ) 

        for place in query_result.places:
        # Returned places from a query are place summaries.
            Name = place.name
            Name = Name.encode('utf-8')#Encodage en UTF-8 obligatoire pour éviter les erreurs : "UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character..."
            Latitude = place.geo_location['lat']
            Longitude = place.geo_location['lng']
            # The following method has to make a further API call.
            place.get_details()
            Details = place.details
            Address = place.formatted_address
            Address = Address.encode('utf-8') 
            Phone_International = place.international_phone_number
            Website = place.website

        Result = str(MyType) + ";" + Name + ";" + Address + ";" + str(Phone_International) + ";" + str(Latitude) + ";" + str(Longitude)
+ ";" + str(Website)
        print Result

####################################
### Script
####################################

Location = "4.04827,9.70428"
MyType = "DOES_NOT_WORK"
ExtractGoogleHotspots(Location, MyType)
```

Code that doesn't work:

```
    # Configuration de l'encodage (a mettre dans tous les scripts)
    # encoding: utf-8

    ####################################
    ### CLASS
    #################################### 

def ExtractGoogleHotspots(Location,Type):
            from googleplaces import GooglePlaces, types, lang
            YOUR_API_KEY = 'XXXXXXX'
            google_places = GooglePlaces(YOUR_API_KEY)
            MyType = "[types.TYPE_"+Type+"]"
            # You may prefer to use the text_search API, instead.
            query_result = google_places.nearby_search(
                location=Location, #Location could be a name or coordinates in english format : 4.04827,9.70428
                keyword='',
                radius=1000,#Radius in meters (max = 50 000)
                types=MyType #Specify the Type
                ) 

            for place in query_result.places:
            # Returned places from a query are place summaries.
                Name = place.name
                Name = Name.encode('utf-8')#Encodage en UTF-8 obligatoire pour éviter les erreurs : "UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character..."
                Latitude = place.geo_location['lat']
                Longitude = place.geo_location['lng']
                # The following method has to make a further API call.
                place.get_details()
                Details = place.details
                Address = place.formatted_address
                Address = Address.encode('utf-8') 
                Phone_International = place.international_phone_number
                Website = place.website

                Result = str(MyType) + ";" + Name + ";" + Address + ";" + str(Phone_International) + ";" + str(Latitude) + ";" + str(Longitude)
        + ";" + str(Website)
                print Result

        ####################################
        ### Script
        ####################################

        Location = "4.04827,9.70428"
        MyType = "PHARMACY"
        ExtractGoogleHotspots(Location, MyType)
```

How to resolve the problem to have a variable to define the Types part?

Comment: If your edit answers the question and the code works, then you should post below instead of updating the question. Now it is not clear what you are asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To concatenate the type name with `TYPE_` in take it from `types` you can use `getattr`

```py
MyTypes = [ getattr(types, 'TYPE_' + Type.upper() ]
```

Comment: Thanks Marco.
I tried but I have the following Error: UnboundLocalError: local variable 'types' referenced before assignment

Comment: @neonepthys are you importing the google library as in your first example?

Comment: I'm a newbie in coding and I don't get your point. I modified the code with the one you have posted and it did not work

Comment: Can I see the full code of your first example (the one you said that works)? (do not include your API Key!!!)

Comment: See below the full code.Your might have to install the Python-Google-script: pip install python-google-places

Comment: @neonepthys edit your question to include the full code and please remove your api key. I edited my answer, try this new code. Thanks

Comment: I have cleaned my request. How to concatenate Mytype value to make it work?

Comment: As I said after the code, you can use `append` to add new types to the `MyType` array or assign `MyType` with all the types you want.

Comment: Sorry but I don't see how to concatenate it. Could you please send an exemple?

Comment: @neonepthys examples added.

Comment: Thank you for your patience but it does not answer my needs. I have a value "PHARMACY", how to concatenate it to obtain MyType. In your exemple you don't concatenate the value sent in parameter (PHARMACY), you specify an entire parameter from scratch wich cannot work.

Comment: No problem, I just hope it solves your problem. Don't forget to accept the answer by clicking on the gray check mark below the voting system if it does.

Comment: I send "Pharmacy" to the fonction, how to concatenate it to obtain "MyType = [types.TYPE_PHARMACY]"

Comment: You can just use a simple conditional. `if Type == 'Pharmacy': MyType = [types.TYPE_PHARMACY]` for example or you can use `getattr`. `MyType = [ getattr(types, 'TYPE_' + Type.upper()) ]`.

Comment: getattr was exactly was I was looking for. Problem resolved. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Ok, I will change my answer to include `getattr`.